# Paypal sandbox doesn't notify IPN handler on localhost?

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I'm trying to fetch all the global variables and log it into log.txt file.
It works great with on a real webserver, but when I try it using on localhost it seems like it doesn't notify my IPN handler.

Purchase URL:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&amount=".urlencode($row['price'])."&business=".urlencode($paypalemail)."&item_name=".urlencode($row['name'])."&item_number=".urlencode($row['ID']."_".$_SESSION['ID'])."&return=http://127.0.0.1/Mywebsite/purchase.php"."&rm=2&notify_url=http://127.0.0.1/Mywebsite/includes/paypalipn.php"."&cancel_return=http://127.0.0.1/Mywebsite/purchase.php"."&no_note=1&currency_code=USD
```

paypalipn.php:

```
<?php
define("_VALID_PHP", true);
file_put_contents("log.txt", print_r($GLOBALS, true)."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

When I complete a purchase through Paypal sandbox, no log.txt file is been created though.
Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: When you say you're trying to use it on localhost, are you setting the actual IPN URL to http://localhost/whatever.php?  If so, that won't work.  PayPal would be posting data to themselves in that case.  You'll need to use your public IP address or setup a domain that points to your localhost server there so you can use that as your IPN URL instead of localhost.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your answer!
I understand, so if I use localhost on my own PC, how can I do that ?
When I enter my IP address in the explorer, it doesn't point to my website.

Comment: Setup a vhost on your local web server for some.domain.com.  Then create a DNS record for that domain to point to your public IP address.  Then make sure your router/firewall is allowing public traffic on port 80.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your still looking for a solution, one way to do it would be to use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) in order to `expose` your local web-server.